# Auth guard driver [api] is not defined?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I use this library `jwt-auth-guard` in Laravel 5.3.

When I try open page I get error:

```
InvalidArgumentException in AuthManager.php line 99:
Auth guard driver [api] is not defined.
```

How can I fix it? I made everything that was need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, please check you guard driver setup into `config/auth.php` first. You can cross check this from [GIT repo](https://github.com/irazasyed/jwt-auth-guard).

Let me know if any concern from above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tymondesigns/jwt-auth package first check that you are downloading the latest version (1.0.0-rc.2 for this time) or you can just update your composer

```
composer update
```

and also delete your old jwt file from config folder and publish again also run!

```
php artisan jwt:secret
```