# Laravel 5.8 Auth guard [api] is not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-passport

When I use auth api guard for my controller I am facing with the following exception

> Auth guard [api] is not defined

When I remove Authorization in request header, my controller work is true but when I add Authorization and accept to request header, I get this error.

My route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'category','middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
  Route::post('add', 'Api\CategoryController@addCategory');
  Route::post('edit', 'Api\CategoryController@editCategory');
  Route::get('get/{id}', 'Api\CategoryController@getCategory');
  Route::get('get', 'Api\CategoryController@getCategory');
  Route::get('delete', 'Api\CategoryController@deleteCategory');
});
```

auth.php file:

```
 'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

and i added Passport::routes() to AuthServiceProvider.php and i migrated passport migration and i installed passport for create passport client access

i think every thing is ok but get error

Comment: is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39409166/auth-guard-driver-api-is-not-defined) help you ?

Comment: can you try clearing config cache

Comment: @Joseph which Answer?

Comment: @AWSPS i clear cache and its work but get messege Unauthenticated!! my token is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear config cache to take effect.
for Unauthenticated it means token is not valid or is not passed correctly

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#passing-the-access-token